# Launch an UWP app from Background Task

Tags: c#, uwp

I have created an UWP app with out-of-process background task following this link

[out of process background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task)

This is My Background Task

```
namespace MyTask
{
    public sealed class FirstTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        private BackgroundTaskDeferral backgroundTaskDeferral;
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            DefaultLaunch();
        }

        async void DefaultLaunch()
        {
            // The URI to launch
            var uriBing = new Uri("mytempapp://test");
            try
            {
                // Launch the URI
                var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uriBing);  // Throws Error 
             }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

This background Task is activated on Timezone Change which works fine

```
BackgroundTaskBuilder taskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder { Name = "FirstTask", TaskEntryPoint = "MyTask.FirstTask" };
taskBuilder.SetTrigger(new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.TimeZoneChange, false));
BackgroundTaskRegistration myFirstTask = taskBuilder.Register();
```

Problem is when DefaultLaunch() is called it throws error. Ideal case will be it should open my App registered with a URI scheme

```
System.Runtime.InteropService.COMException(0x80070578) invalid window Handler

This API must be called from a thread with a CC
```

Comment: You can launch another background task on some other trigger. Its not possible to launch application from background task.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you **cannot** launch a URI from a background task. This would be disruptive for the user, because she could not be able to identify why the app is starting and **could be misused easily**. Even worse, from a background thread the user could not be able to **identify which app caused the launch** (to be able to uninstall the malicious one).

As the error message states, this API can be **called only from an UI thread** - meaning a thread associated with an app view. Background task has no app view association and hence cannot launch an URI. same goes for `LaunchFileAsync` and other `Launcher` APIs.

Comment: What's solution for this. I need to launch my app when ever timezone is changed how can I do that ???

Comment: You could trigger a Toast Notification and have that launch your app?

Comment: Triggering a Toast notification is a way to get the user's attention and suggest him to open the app, but that is as far as you can get with the UWP API. There is no way to launch the app directly...